# How to subtract two numbers with particular decimal increments in Excel

Tags: excel, decimal, distance

In Excel (2016, mac) I have two rows of four-digit numbers with two-digit decimals, which have an increment of .25 
For example: 1000.25 and 1001.50
The "distance" between the numbers in this example is 5, as we have quarter increments.

Which formula do I need to calculate the distance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just divide the difference by the increment size, something like the following:

```
=(A3-A2)/0.25
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work. I get a #VALUE!. I also tried a comma instead of period

Comment: Maybe share a screenshot - this is an extremely simple formula so you should be able to replicate it.

Comment: I found the problem. A2 and A3 also need a comma instead of period